# Creating an "if else" statement with vectors > 1

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm trying to organize some data, working with the "tidyverse" package. I have a dataframe which contains "gender inequality" index scores for each country, with the dates for when the data was collected heading the columns (2000, 2005, 2010) and then the country scores in the rows.

I need to add these scores and divide them by 3, 2, or nothing depending on whether a score for one of the years is 0--so for example if I have

```
 Year     2000    2005   2010
 Norway    0      0.106  0.080
```

I want to add all three (0 + 0.106 + 0.080) and divide by 2. And so on for all countries, dividing by three if all years have score, and by nothing if only a year has a score

To do this I have constructed these if else statements:

```
 GII_data_FINAL <- if (GII_data2$`2000` == 0 & GII_data2$`2005` != 0 & GII_data2$`2010` != 0 ){GII_data2 %>% 
     mutate(GII_mean_score = (`2000`+ `2005`+ `2010`)/2)
 } else if (GII_data2$`2000`= 0 & GII_data2$`2005` == 0 & GII_data2$`2010` != 0) {GII_data2 %>% 
     mutate(GII_mean_score = `2000`+ `2005`+ `2010`)
 } else if (GII_data2$`2000`== 0 & GII_data2$`2005` != 0 & GII_data2$`2010` == 0) {GII_data2 %>% 
     mutate(GII_mean_score = `2000`+ `2005`+ `2010`)
 } else if (GII_data2$`2000`!= 0 & GII_data2$`2005`!= 0 & GII_data2$`2010` != 0) {GII_data2 %>% 
     mutate (GII_mean_score = (`2000`+ `2005`+ `2010`)/3)
 } else if (GII_data$`2000`!= 0 & GII_data$`2005` == 0 & GII_data$`2010` != 0) {GII_data2 %>% 
     mutate(GII_mean_score = (`2000`+ `2005`+ `2010`)/2)
 } else if (GII_data$`2000`!= 0 & GII_data$`2005` == 0 & GII_data$`2010` == 0) { GII_data2 %>% 
     mutate(GII_mean_score = `2000`+ `2005`+ `2010`)
 } else if (GII_data$`2000`!= 0 & GII_data$`2005` != 0 & GII_data$`2010` == 0) {GII_data2 %>% 
     mutate(GII_mean_score = (`2000`+ `2005`+ `2010`)/2)
 } else if (GII_data2$`2000` == 0 & GII_data2$`2005` == 0 & GII_data2$`2010` == 0) {GII_data2 %>% 
     mutate(GII_mean_score = `2000`+ `2005`+ `2010`)
 }
```

However I get the statement

> ```
> "Warning messages:
> 1: In if (GII_data2$`2000` == 0 & GII_data2$`2005` != 0 & GII_data2$`2010` !=  :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> 2: In if (GII_data2$`2000` & GII_data2$`2005` == 0 & GII_data2$`2010` !=  :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> 3: In if (GII_data2$`2000` == 0 & GII_data2$`2005` != 0 & GII_data2$`2010` ==  :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> 4: In if (GII_data2$`2000` != 0 & GII_data2$`2005` != 0 & GII_data2$`2010` !=  :
>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"
> ```

I've researched and I understand why I get this statement, but I'm not sure how else to get R to do what I want it to, as ifelse would not work with having several conditions (as far as I understand).

I'd appreciate any help at all!

Comment: Replace `0` with `NA`, and use `rowMeans(d[ , -1], na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

multiple lines ( with

> else if

in your case) is generally a hint to write a function. Actually, you would like to calculate an average but exclude zeros. You could define:

> average_exclude_0 = function(x){mean(x[x!=0])}

Then you could apply this function to corresponding columns, e.g. with **mutate_at**.

EDIT: cannot add comments, but I would think Henrik's suggestion is the best approach: it is fast and methodologically correct, since zeros are actually NAs

Answer (score 0):

Being aware that R enthusiasts will hate it, why you don't just loop through the rows?

```
for (row in 1:nrow(your_dataframe)) {
    n_entries = 0
    sum = 0
    for (col in 1:ncol(your_dataframe) {
        if (your_dataframe[row,col] != 0) {
            n_entries = n_entries + 1
            sum = sum + your_dataframe[row,col]
        }
    }
    result = NULL
    if (n_entries > 0) { result = sum / n_entries }
    else {
         result = NA
    }
    # Do something with the result
}
```

You should wrap it into functions and ideally use the apply functionality I guess. My solution might give you a more general idea of how to do this (in other languages as well).

Comment: In the end the comment above was a faster solution, but thank you for this, it certainly taught me a new function in R!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a function to calculate average excluding zeros:

> mean_excluding_0 = function(x){mean(x[x!=0])}

Then you could use **mutate_at** to apply this function to corresponding columns.